# Autocomplete ONLY suggested text without brackets and arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I am using vscode with python extension.
When writing code and after pressing tab I want to autocomplete only the name of function/class/method without inserting suggested brackets and arguments. That's how it worked for me for a long time, but something has changed and I have no idea what.

That's how it works now

[image]

Comment: have you changed the python language server setting (Microsoft, PyLance, Jeti)

Comment: @rioV8 I've been always using Jedi as python language server, but thanks to your question I've changed it to Pylance and now its working as I want. Thank you very much! However, I still wonder how it happened that behavior of autocomplete has changed overnight without my interference in the settings.